# Pair Programming and Display on an IMAX

Tags: extreme-programming

I responded to an employment opportunity for an XP developer. I have done several XP projects early in the 2000s, but not lately after Scrum has come into wide practice.

The recruiter said they practice XP, particularly pair programming. And they project the pair programming session on an IMAX screen visible to anyone in the room. I have practiced pair programming, and I love it, for its many benefits - particularly the instant code review and very short feedback loop. Also, a great way to spread knowledge and experience. But our pair programming sessions were private conversations between two people. Sometimes groggy and tired. Sometimes clueless as to how to proceed. Sometimes needing another cup of coffee - you know, human attributes in a real-life working session.

Does anyone out there in XPland practice project a pair programming session on an IMAX screen? Or a large wall display (IMAX is extreme!).

If you do practice that, can you please let us know the rationale and the benefits?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Project Management, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what they are doing there. There are a few potential possibilities.

1) They are just enjoying a large screen. I find it incredibly hard to believe that it is truly IMAX. It is probably just a projector or a big screen. I like screens over projectors because I find the screens to cause less eye strain.

2) Maybe they are doing [Mob Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVqUcNKVbYg). This gets many of the benefits pair programming applied to the whole team. It also has all of the challenges applied to the team too - you will notice in the linked video multiple hand sanitizer dispensers.

3) They are doing this to drive extreme transparency. This can be good or bad depending on the company. Most companies with extreme transparency also develop a culture of understanding and empathy. A much smaller percentage use it as a weapon. If you are concerned about this, maybe they can let you hang out in the development area while people are working during the interview so you can see for yourself.